# Login CSRF protection on an apache reverse proxy with form based ldap authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, proxy, csrf, reverse-proxy

We have a reverse proxy who handles the user authentication using a form and ldap authentication. This is working fine.

Now, i am asked to implement CSRF login protection, described here: https://support.detectify.com/support/solutions/articles/48001048951-login-csrf

I read the easiest way is to implement Double submit Cookies, where when the form is loaded a token is generated and passed within the response to the user. When the user submits the form, the form then checks if the cookie is the same.

I cannot use this implementation because the form does not handle the authentication, but the mod_auth_form module does.
Here is our setup:

vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.example.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test.example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
  SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder On
  SSLCompression off
  SSLCertificateFile test.example.com.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile test.example.com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile test.example.com.ca
  Alias "/auth" "/var/www/auth"
  Customlog /var/log/apache2/test.example.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test.example.com-error.log
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/auth/" noauth
  <Location /auth/logout>
    SetHandler form-logout-handler
    AuthType form
    AuthName realm
    AuthFormLogoutLocation /
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
  </Location>
  <Location />
    AuthType form
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    AuthName realm
    AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation %{REQUEST_URI}
    Session On
    SessionCryptoPassphrase secretphrase
    SessionCookieName session path=/
    <RequireAny>
      Require ldap-group CN=webapp_users,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
      Require env noauth
    </RequireAny>
    ErrorDocument 401 "/auth/login.html"
    AuthLDAPBindDN ldap@example.com
    AuthLDAPBindPassword secretpass
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://example.com/OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com?sAMAccountName,displayName?sub"
    AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 5
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
    AuthLDAPSubgroupAttribute member
    AuthLDAPSubGroupClass group
  </Location>
  ProxyPass /auth/ !
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass               /             https://webapp.example.com/
  ProxyPassReverse        /             https://webapp.example.com/
  ProxyRequests           Off
  AllowEncodedSlashes     NoDecode
  Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</VirtualHost>
```

And the login form looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="auth/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="auth/assets/example_com.ico" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function init() {
        var sitename = window.location.hostname;
        document.getElementById("sitename").innerHTML =sitename;
        document.title = sitename;
        document.getElementById("username").focus();
      }

      function tryLogin() {
        localStorage.setItem("tryLogin", true);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
      <div id=wrap-logo>
        <div id=logo></div>
      </div>
    <div id="content">
      <h1><div id='sitename'>empty</div> requires a login</h1>
      <form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="tryLogin()" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username" name="httpd_username" placeholder="Username" value="" />
        <label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" id="password" name="httpd_password" placeholder="Password" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, basically what happens here; If you are not logged in, you are redirected to the 401 errorpage which is the login page. When you submit the form, the authentication credentials are passed to the mod_ldap module which creates a session cookie if authenticated properly. After that, anything but /auth/* is proxied to the destination.

Is there any way i could implement CSRF login protection in this setup?

I have tried [mod_csrf](http://mod-csrf.sourceforge.net), but can't get it to work, and i'd rather not use it because its an alpha release.

Answer (score -1):

I mod_csrf is impossible together with the mod_auth_form because mod_auth_form  will always handle your request first.

Just install php on your apache server and do like the link you send.`
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
        setcookie("CSRFtoken", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24);

```
        <form action="loginchecker.php" method="post">
            <input name="user">
            <input name="pass" type="password">
            <input name="CSRFtoken" type="hidden" value="' . $token . '">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>;`
```

You can redirect the form to a page that check if the token en cookie are correct then fill with this page a new form and send it directly with js.
`document.forms["loginFormname"].submit();`

Comment: That link is where i am reffering to in my question.